# Need to truncate the present quarter data and reload only that quarter data without touch other records

Tags: sql

I need to delete the present quarter records but existing records can not be deleted.

In fiscal_quarter column FY23Q1/FY23Q2/FY23Q3/FY23Q4 are the values for that column
Need help

```
insert into my_schema.my_table 
select * from my_schema.my_table 
where fiscal_quarter = 'FY%Q%'
```

Comment: collect that data into temp table and then truncate, load data from temp table.

Comment: I need to retain values which are not in that quarter only that quarter data need to be truncated and reload with coming data with in that quarter

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using (and the PL/SQL tag seems completely unrelated as you are not asking for a stored procedure)

Comment: which RDBMS are you using MySQL,SQL Server,....

Comment: I am using Greenplum

Answer (score 0):

Does the following do what you want?

```
delete from my_schema.my_table 
where fiscal_quarter = 'FY%Q%';
```